# Upvoting and flagging at the same time?

Tags: discussion, flagging

**Expample::**

[How to keep extensions from Magento Connect up2date without connect-manager?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174281/how-to-keep-extensions-from-magento-connect-up2date-without-connect-manager)

I've upvoted the answer because somebody made (useful) thoughts about it ...

... at the other hand I've flagged it as `not an answer` because it wasn't what I intended ...

**Question(s):**

- What is the flag for?
- What is caused by flagging? (in this case)
- What is more important - flag or upvote?

I'm not sure about ATM ... but upvoting and flagging it as `no answer` at the same time doesn't fit together.

I'm curios about your thoughts :)

(GN8 - before more strange ideas come to mind :P)